# Quatro PDF How to wrap results of output and keep formatting

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I got the results of a Welch Two Sample t-test, but I can't figure out how to wrap the long text of the "alternative hypothesis" line.
[image: Output in pdf document]

I tried changing the results to asis, but this eliminated the formatting and made it less readable.[image: Output with asis picked as result]

I also have tried the below global chunk options-

```r
    tidy.opts = list(width.cutoff = 80),
    tidy = TRUE
```

Is there a way to keep the formatting of the actual output but get it to wrap when the text of the results is too long for the page?

Some quick code that generates a t-test where the alternative hypothesis does not equal 0

```r
t.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should put together and include in your question a minimal document that generates this, so people can modify it to do what you want.  If we start from scratch we'll probably solve a completely different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
the_test = t.test(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))

max_width = 50 ## set wrap width

options(width = max_width) ## set width for printing

the_test |>
  capture.output() |> 
  strwrap(width = max_width) |> ## re-wrap initial output
  cat(fill = TRUE) ## make cat observe print width
```

Explanation: the print method for class `htest` (results of a hypothesis test) uses `cat` to output some header information (check with `stats:::print.htest` + ENTER). `cat` doesn't care about print width specifications, unless told so via its `fill` argument. So we first capture the print output, re-wrap lines to the desired width and feed it back to another `cat`, this time with `fill = TRUE` to observe the print width specified with `options(...)`.

Comment: This was super close, but the results ended with losing the new line arguments after each value in capture.output(), making it hard to read again.  Is there a way to only manipulate line 6 of the vector from capture.output() to wrap that portion and keep the formatting of the rest of the results? (the alternative hypothesis line)? or is there a way to add a new line after each part in capture.output()?

Comment: I tried changing the sep = "\n" which is better, but it still looks a little wonky as it create a new line on the very long alternative hypothesis line instead of wrapping it.

Comment: Try `strwrap(width = max_width, simplify = FALSE) |> unlist() |> cat(sep = "\n")`.

Comment: Yep :) That got the job done. Thanks so much for the help!